# How will a CDN work with my site?

Tags: mysql, file-upload, cdn, content-delivery-network

I have tried to look for answers for my question but haven't found anything conclusive.

I have a site which, among other things, stores member pictures & thumbnails.  They are in separate directories, and within each directory are a cascade of folder names based on properties of the image.  This is to prevent thousands of images being in one directory for performance reasons.

for example, a typical image has a URL like:

www.mysite.com/thumbs/100x75/04/18/s3hf9sj_939swzl.jpg

The file location and name are stored in a mysql database so they can be dynamically displayed.

How would a CDN be implemented for my images? Can I recursively select all the images in a directory to be uploaded to the CDN?  How often would it update this file information?

And finally, what might happens when the database retrieves a url like the one above?  Will the CDN automatically redirect the user to something like this?

www.cdn.mysite.com/thumbs/100x75/04/18/s3hf9sj_939swzl.jpg

Or will I have to design my database differently?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you choose to migrate to a CDN and not change your URL scheme you would have to make sure requests to `www.mysite.com/thumbs/` are routed to your CDN (at `www.cdn.mysite.com/thumbs/`).

You also need to change your method of saving images to also save a copy to the CDN, or you could create a synchronization script to run periodically, but then you would need to serve your resources from two locations; from your own if the file is not present on the CDN, which would increase the complexity of your setup.

I would make sure I store my resources directly at my CDN at the same time I backup locally and would migrate to a separate domain form my CDN (to allow more concurrent downloads from the user).

Comment: For some reason I thought CDNs worked like cacheing, where they would automatically be added to the network when they were retrieved from the 'origin' server.

Comment: No, they do not automagically work like that. It's not impossible to create some sort of middleware to make it *seem* that way, but I do not know of any such solutions. For more on CDN's, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network